# CQL3 (Cassandra) upsert increasing a counter

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3, upsert

I have the following CQL3 table.

```
CREATE TABLE UserKarma (
  user_id uuid, 
  sub_type text, 
  karma counter, 
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, sub_type)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
```

How do I either insert or update (single query) a value and increase the counter? If the entry doesn't exist, since the counter is `0` by default, then all new records created with this upsert should be `1`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

```
UPDATE UserKarma SET karma = karma + 1 where user_id = d9d9354a-32e9-46d7-a56c61e21b486ae3 and sub_type = 'test';
```